# IAP - Hosted Content - Asset Catalog Compiler Error - The output directory ".../.../..." does not exits

Tags: in-app-purchase, xcode6.1, ios8.1, asset-catalog, iap-hosted-content

I have an app which is 50MB+ in size. It is filled with image sets. Since the app has IAP I would like to download image sets on demand (when the user buys one image set). In order to do that I am trying to use apple's hosted content option.

I created a new project with the correct name/bundle ID and configured everything in iTunes conect. In order to deliver these IAP image sets I used a Asset catalog for every IAP product.
However, when I want to archieve the product Xcode gives me the following message:

/Users/MyCompany/Desktop/Programming projects/Tutorials/Vegetables1/Vegetables1/Media.xcassets: 
**The output directory** "/Users/MyCompany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vegetables1-dzbpbuiozhaliyezacnqehsgubdt/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Vegetables1/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Library/InAppPurchaseContent/Vegetables1/Contents" **does not exist**.

The Media.xcassets is empty... I didn't add any picture. No matter what I do it keeps giving me this error.

The Media.xcasset is correctly added in the `Copy Bundle Resources` and is visible via `Finder`.

I could add all the images manually without the Asset catalog. I don't think this a good approach but if it doesn't work I will have no other choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this if you have a file listed under your **Copy Bundle Resources** that is not the images xcasset.

For me, since I also have music with my IAP pack, I had to simply add the music to the pack to make it build properly. Experiment with blank files, or other items such that you can include with the IAP that are not necessarily needed but can be included with the IAP in Xcode.

Comment: So far what I have read based on @stewjacks and your solution there is no way of using .xassets outside the app bundle and in my case scenario. I think you are both right. I will test it =).

Comment: I'm currently doing the same. I've got it hosted and just trying to implement the code to. Download and install the .pkg

Comment: I ran into this problem when trying to use an Asset Catalog with a FinderSync extension. You are correct, @ErikBean, you can only do this if there's another file in Copy Bundle Resources. I added an empty file, and the compilation error went away. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help! :) just remember to mark my answer as correct. I'm currently trying to find an efficient way to unpack apple hosted packs -.-' if you see a way, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Asset catalogs are resources in your bundle, so you can't modify or add them at runtime. You also can't reference a resource that isn't available at compile time. You'll either have to prepackage all IAPs and unlock them via purchase (using asset catalogs if you'd like), or package your IAP content in a different format (probably a zip with raw images and a dictionary) so you can read them from a local directory outside the bundle.

Comment: I've run into this same problem. Am I only limited to containing it on the app with the image xcassets file or is there a way to setup IAP for Apple to host so that it will host (and essentially download) the .xassets?

Comment: ST1 - "Asset catalogs are resources in your bundle, so you can't modify or add them at runtime" - this statement means that asset catalogs CAN NOT be used at run time (via downloadable content)? ST2 - "You also can't reference a resource that isn't available at compile time" - What do you mean by "reference a resource"? For me this means I can't run code which needs resources that are not available, but I can write it as long as I don't run it (which will cause a crash). I will test it as soon as I update Xcode :)

Comment: 1. You can't modify an asset catalog that's bundled with your main app *ever* because you can't modify anything in your app bundle at runtime. It's pre-compiled. What you're actually doing is loading content from the bundle (on disk) into memory and modifying that.
2. You can't, in your main app, reference an asset catalog from an in-app purchase that won't be available at compile-time.

Comment: What you want to do is put your content in the IAP, copy it from cache on download to some save documents directory on disk, and read the images with `UIImage(contentsOfFile: *path*)`. I think the reason you can add them to your IAP in the first place is because Mac App Store IAPs use the same template as iOS IAPs, and you can almost certainly put asset catalogs in an IAP for the Mac App Store.